# Connect multiple TinyMCE textareas to show anchors and links

Tags: jquery, plugins, tinymce

I have two TinyMCE textareas on the same form. They are both initiaited in the same call using the element option.

```
tinyMCE.init({
theme : "advanced",
mode : "exact",
elements: "description1,description2",
```

I also have the Advanced Link plugin enabled:

```
plugins : "advlink"
```

If an anchor is added to one textarea, it is not available to me in the other textareas link dialogue. Only the anchors added in description1 are available whilst adding links to description1.

I would like to somehow read through all the textareas initaited on the page and allow users to select anchors from any of them. If this required an ajax solution I would then like to specify off page textareas to look through for anchors as well.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to somehow read through all the textareas initaited on
>   the page and allow users to select anchors from any of them. If this
>   required an ajax solution I would then like to specify off page
>   textareas to look through for anchors as well.

You do not need to use ajax here, because all the code is on the page.
All you need to do is to search for anchors in

```
tinymce.get('description1').getContent(); //and
tinymce.get('description2').getContent();
```

Comment: yes, that will get the content of each text area, but how do you tell the advlink plugin that the content form both is available for anchors? the plugin itself would need to be communicated with surely?